# PHP DOTNET hell

Tags: c#, php, .net

I'm quite a newbie in PHP and today I discovered [DOTNET](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php) class.
So I studied manual, surfed the web to find some example and finally wrote my test app:

1. Created a new DLL using Framework 4.0 Client Profile
2. Signed the assembly with a strong name key
3. Marked assembly as COM-Visible

This is the test code I wrote

```
using System;

namespace CSharpCOM
{
    public class CSharpCOMClass
    {
        public string Base64(string s)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s));
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled the assembly and then registered in GAC (`gacutil /if fullpath\CSharpCOM.dll`).
If I use `gacutil /l CSharpCOM` I see

> La cache di assembly globale contiene gli assembly seguenti:
>   csharpcom, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=beb607ae770f5750, processorArchitecture=MSIL
>
> Numero di elementi = 1

So everything seems ok.
Then wrote this basic php:

```
<?php
try{
    $csclass = new DOTNET("CSharpCOM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, " .
                          "PublicKeyToken=beb607ae770f5750",
                          "CSharpCOM.CSharpCOMClass");
    echo $csclass->Base64("Test string"),"\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

Whatever I try, loading page hosted in Apache (`http://localhost/test01/dotnet.php`) I always get

> Caught exception: Failed to instantiate .Net object [CreateInstance]
>   [0x80070002] Impossibile trovare il file specificato.
>   Translation could be: unable to find specified file

Just another thing: using some example (a very basic one [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/04/24/how-to-use-.net-assemblies-in-php.aspx)) I read that my assembly (when registered) should be found on `%windir%\assembly`, but I'm only able to find it in `%windi%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CSharpCOM\v4.0_1.0.0.0__beb607ae770f5750`: is this correct? Why don't I have it on first directory?

More: if I create another framework project and try to add a .NET reference I can't find my assembly: is this related to the fact I'm not able to load this assembly from PHP?

Last note: I tried it on Windows XP Professional SP3 32bit and on Windows Seven Enterprise 64bit

**UPDATE:**
This works:

```
$form = new DOTNET('System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089', 'System.Windows.Forms.Form');
```

but this one does not:

```
$form = new DOTNET('System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089', 'System.Windows.Forms.Form');`
```

Is it possible that PHP can load only framework 2.0 assemblies?

Comment: Negative control: can you load classes from an existing assembly, e.g. mscorlib? It sounds as though the problem here isn’t PHP but rather that your assembly isn’t properly registered.

Comment: yes, I can use `$stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Collections.Stack");`

Comment: OK, follow-up question: can you load an existing, signed assembly, providing its full name in PHP (including public key)?

Comment: Removing spaces is useless: same result :( I give a try with some other assembly, but for a couple of hours I'm busy... so I post my answer this evening (here is 4.20PM). Thanks

Comment: Regarding the directory, this is normal as far as I remember. The “%Windir%\Assembly” directory doesn’t actually physically exist but it’s populated when you open it in Explorer with information found elsewhere (i.e. the GAC).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: one little update before leaving

Comment: Permissions problem maybe? Does it work when PHP is executed from CLI as a normal user?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: sorry for stupid question... what should I try? I'm a newbie :)

Comment: open a command prompt in the directory with your php script and execute the script using i.e. "c:\php\php.exe script.php"

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: using CLI I have same results

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue:  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55847   Can you target your DLL to .NET 3.5 or lower?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why you would ever want to do this. If the server has .NET installed, then it likely has ASP.NET support, so why even bother with php at all?

Comment: @jrummell: I must run my website with some PHP portal, better if using Apache. Later I should try to move under Linux. I'm thinking about write some logic in .NET (I'm skilled with this) and use it in PHP. Do you think it's crazy? Do you have some advise? Thanks

Comment: @Marco a bit crazy? Yes :). My advice is to pick a single platform (php or .NET) and stick with it for the entire project. Or at least keep the UI in php and make calls to an ASP.NET web service layer. Mixing the two together sounds like trouble.

Comment: @jrummell: yes, probably you're right. I'm still searching my way and I'm in a mess because PHP is standard and you can use everywhere, while ASP no; using Mono I can run .NET apps under Linux and ASP pages too. Using PHP for UI and continuosly call webservice layer developed in ASP is an option I've already thought, but it's nor "light" nor fast. Don't know, gotta think about it. Anyway thanks for your opinion that I agree with :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55847) the DOTNET class is not loading .NET 4.0 DLLs.  If you're not using any of the new libraries in .NET 4.0 you can target your to .NET 3.5 or lower by opening the project properties and on the "Application" tab change the "Target framework" to ".NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile"

Now when you install your DLL into the GAC it will get installed into the CLR 2.0 GAC and should be able to be loaded using the DOTNET class in PHP.

Comment: Thanks a lot: compiling using framework 3.5 solved my problem!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

There is a library out there called NetPhp (https://github.com/david-garcia-garcia/netphp) that will let you:

- Use any .Net binaries (even without COM Visibility) and ANY version of the .Net framework including CLR4
- Dump a PHP class model
- Iterate over .Net collections directly from PHP
  PHP class model generation, to use PHP classes as if it where .Net
  Automatic propagation of .Net errors into native PHP exceptions that can be properly handled
- Acces native enums and static methods
- Use class constructors with parameters
- Debug .Net and PHP code at the same time as if it was a single application.

There is a project with code samples here:

https://github.com/david-garcia-garcia/netphp-sample

This is what a piece of code with NetPhp looks like:

```
$datetime = $runtime->TypeFromName("System.DateTime");
$datetime->Instantiate();

echo $datetime->ToShortDateString()->Val(); // Outputs 01/01/0001

// We can only use Int32 from native PHP, so parse
// an Int64 that is equivalent to (long) in the DateTime constructor.
$ticks = $runtime->TypeFromName("System.Int64")->Parse('98566569856565656');
$ticks = \ms\System\netInt64::_Parse('98566569856565656');

$datetime->Instantiate($ticks);
echo $datetime->ToShortDateString()->Val(); // Outputs 07/05/0313

$now = $runtime->TypeFromName("System.DateTime")->Now;
echo $now->ToShortDateString()->Val(); // Outputs "23/10/2015"

$now = $runtime->TypeFromName("System.DateTime")->Now();
echo $now->ToShortDateString()->Val(); // Outputs "23/10/2015"

$timer = $runtime->TypeFromName("System.Timers.Timer")->Instantiate();
$timer->AutoReset(TRUE);
$timer->AutoReset = TRUE;
```